# Odoo prototype inheritance

Tags: inheritance, odoo

I suppose I've not fully undrestood the prototype inheritance in Odoo.
This is my very basic code where I create 2 new models inheriting from the 'res.partner' model.
I need two new models with some of the functionalities/fields of the 'res.partner' model.

Here is my code:

```
class Hero(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _name = 'heroes_villains.hero'
    _description = "heroes_villains.hero"

class Villain(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _name = 'heroes_villains.villain'
    _description = "heroes_villains.villain"
```

it's all ok if I don't try to load some demo data in this way with demo.xml file:

```
<odoo>
    <data>
          <record id="hero0" model="heroes_villains.hero">
            <field name="name">Thor</field>
            <field name="email">thor@heroes.com</field>
          </record>

          <record id="villain0" model="heroes_villains.villain">
            <field name="name">Magneto</field>
            <field name="email">magneto@villains.com</field>
          </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

When I load this I get the following error:

```
    raise TypeError("Mixing apples and oranges: %s in %s" % (item, self))
TypeError: Mixing apples and oranges: res.partner(2,) in heroes_villains.hero(1,)
```

I've read online about it but I really don't understand how to get rid of it.
About my understanding I was expecting that my definitions of Hero and Villain model inherit all the model res.partner and if I have all the fields of the superclass available.
Where is my mistake ? Or my misunderstanding the inheritance ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the Error is raised by the demo data?

Comment: It's not raised "by" the demo data but "when" I use them and also if I try to set the value through the form I did.

Comment: Can you add the code behind the field? That would be the field definition, it's default and compute methods if existing and create and write if they were overridden and are using this field.

Comment: There is no further code. It's just this small example to check if inheritance works or not.
There are just the views but very simple.